# Understanding the At-Most-Once-Property in a concurrent program

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, operating-system, atomic

I am trying to understand the at-most-once property which states:

An attribute of an assignment statement x = e in which either (1) x is not read by another process and e contains at most one reference to a variable changed by another process, or (2) x is not written by another process and e contains no references to variables changed by other processes.

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
co x = x+1; // y= y=1; oc;
```

satisfies the property because x is not read by the second process and has no critical section

```
int x = 1, y = 1;
co <x = x + y;> 
// y = 0;
// x = x - y;
oc
```

I don't understand how this program satisfies the property though. The first statement is an atomic statement so it is not valid anyways but y=0 will affect the third statement x result so I don't understand how this satisfies the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering what this might mean... and it being a particularly wet afternoon, I went and looked and found:

> At-Most-Once Property
>
> Andrews deﬁned a condition called *at-most-once* under which expression evaluations and assignments will appear to be atomic.
>
> A critical reference in an expression is a reference to a variable that is changed by another thread.
>
> 1. An assignment statement `x = e` satisﬁes the at-most-once property if either:
>
>    1.1: `e` contains at most one critical reference and `x` is neither read nor written by another thread, or
>
>    1.2: `e` contains no critical references, in which case `x` may be read or written by other threads.
> 2. An expression that is not in an assignment satisﬁes at-most-once property if it contains no more than one critical reference.
>
> This condition is called at-most-once because there can be at most one shared variable, and the shared variable can be referenced at most one time. ...

I think the key to your puzzle is this sentence:

> ... Assignment statements that satisfy at-most-once property appear to execute atomically even though they are not atomic.

and

> ... That is, we would get the same results from executing these assignment statements even if we were to somehow prevent the interleaving of their machine instructions so that the assignment statements were forced to execute atomically.

Assuming I have understood correctly:

- the `<x = x + y;>` is an atomic read-modify-write.  So that is already atomic -- it does not need to "appear to execute atomically".
- the `y = 0` is *at-most-once* so satisfies (1.2) above and will "appear to execute atomically".  And because it does...
- ...that implies `x = x - y` is also *at-most-once*

...I think.  (Please let us know when you find a definitive answer.)

I'm curious as to what use this is !

Answer (score 0):

your program does not satisfy the At-most-once(AMO) property. Here's why:

Firstly, what is the AMO property? It is a property saying that if an expression e meets certain criteria, we can think of it as being an atomic action. See the Chris Hall answer for how an expression may satisfy this property.

Secondly we need to be familiar with the concept of a 'critical reference': A critical reference is just a different way of saying "a variable that is changed by another process".

So, why does the program in question not satisy the AMO property:
It contains of 3 concurrent statemetents(s1..s3).
S1 is by defenition atomic(as indicated by it being wrapped in angled brackets) so we need not consider it for the AMO property.
S2 satisfies the property as 'e' (the number 0 in this case) contains no critical references.
S3 does not satisfy the AMO property as it contains 2 critical references - both x and y. The references to x and y are by the definition of critical references critical due to the fact that they are changed by s1 and s2 respectively.

Hope this was helpful. Cheers!